# Given two sides and (the sine of) the included angle of a triangle, how to find the third side?

Tags: trigonometry

I have trouble with calculating Triangle Trigometrics. I have 2 sides of a triangle and an angle, and I want to use these to calculate the 3rd side.

An example question might look like:

> You have $\triangle ABC$ with sides $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ and angles $A$, $B$, $C$ in each corner. Find side $AB$, given triangle is an isosceles triangle, $C$ corner angle is an obtuse angle, sides $AB=9$, $BC=9$, and $\sin C=5/6$.

I used all the different formulas from the textbook, yet I can't manage to get a consistent formula to solve this.

Any help on how to solve a question like this? I mean the formula to figure out something like this. What do I need to use?

Comment: Try using the law of cosines. You know $\sin(c)$ so you can find $\cos(c)$.

Comment: @Integrand Thanks I will try more of that now

Comment: Sides are usually labelled in lower case a, b, c with angles in upper case A, B, C. Side c is usually opposite angle C etc. In your text, you want side C (side c is better) which should be opposite angle C, but this is AB = 9??

Comment: Yeah, the opposite side of the angle should be AB=9 @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because triangle is isosceles, all you need to do is to draw a height from point $B$ to $AC$. Let $D$ be the intersection of the height and $AC$. We also know that this height is a median so $AC=2DC=2BC\cos C=2BC\sqrt{1-\sin^2C}$. 
I assume that you have a typo and $C$ is an acute angle, it's impossible for it to be obtuse.

Comment: That is correct, was a typo, sorry for that. Thanks for your input. Just 1 more quick question if you have time? What is the  triangle was not a isosceles, and the sides AC and BC, were 2 different lengths? Lets say, 1, and 6, and C would be 8/9? ( These numbers are taken straight from the exampe, which i do not understand at all)

Comment: @Carlton: get familiar with law of sines and law cosines, that's all you need for problems like this one. Let's say you know $a, c, \sin C$ and you need to find $b$. According to cosine law, $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$. If you just find $\cos C$, you will get a quadratic equation for $b$ (sometimes two solutions are possible).

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. Thanks for the help